# How to specify different editor widgets for the same column in Dojo DataGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I am wondering, is there an official way to specify a different widget editor for the same column in a `DataGrid` (different rows)?

I found `dojox.grid.cells._MultipleEditor`, but it is quite complicated and not officially supported.

This is for creating things like a property sheet with `DataGrid`.

EDIT: People seem to suggest using `dgrid`. However, I am not sure if `dgrid` has this feature.  Also, unfortunately, ... *drum roll*...  *horror music*...  I must support IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there seems to be a way to do it.  Doesn't seem to show much negative side effects (so far)...

1. Create one column for each value type, one after the other.
2. Tag each column with a CSS class to indicate its value type (via `classes`).  For example: `classes="multivalue int"`
3. For each column, tag it with the correct editor widget and the appropriate constraint & options.
4. Put styles on each row (with `onStyleRow`) that correspond to each type.  For example, add a `type-int` class to the row that has an `int` type.
5. Put in a CSS style that initially hides all the multi-valued cells:

   ```
   .dojoxGridCell.multivalue { display:none; }
   ```
6. Un-hide all the cells with the correct type:

   ```
   .dojoxGridRow.type-int .dojoxGridCell.multivalue.int
   {
       display:table-cell;
       *display:block;  /* For IE6/7 */
   }
   ```

   For this to work, obviously, each row must match exactly *one* column.
7. Obviously, you must set all these fields to the same property name.  `DataGrid` allows you to do that.
8. Put `display:none` (via CSS etc.) on all the header cells of multi-valued columns *except the first one*.  Otherwise, you'll end up with too many header cells.